# how do I modify a mocha reporter before a grunt test run?

Tags: coffeescript, mocha.js, gruntjs

I have grunt set up with mocha. It's running fine, but I'd like to get a more detailed report if a test fails from time to time. Naturally I'd just like to run `grunt detailedTest` instead of modifying the grunt file every time. I thought that I'd be able to:

- make a new grunt task named detailedTest
- set that test to change the config of the mocha tester
- then run the tests

That looks like:

```
  grunt.initConfig
    watch:
  ...
  mochaTest:
      files: [ 'test/calc/*.coffee', 'test/*.coffee']
    mochaTestConfig:
      options:
        reporter: 'nyan'
        timeout: 500

grunt.registerTask "spectest", ->
  grunt.config "mochaTestConfig:options:reporter", "spec"
  grunt.log.writeln('done with config: ' 
    + grunt.config "mochaTestConfig:options:reporter")
  grunt.task.run('mochaTest')
```

And the output:

```
$ grunt spectest
Running "spectest" task
done with config: spec

Running "mochaTest:files" (mochaTest) task
 230 _-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_ ...etc
```

Well damn, that's not a spec reporter. How can I modify a config before a test? Or should I pass the value into grunt from the command line somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it 5 minutes later, naturally. The trick is that accessing grunt tests is done with `:` at the command line: `grunt watch:coffee`. But you would modify that config via `.` notation:

```
grunt.registerTask "spectest", ->
    configPos = "mochaTestConfig.options.reporter"
    grunt.log.writeln('before modif config: ' + grunt.config configPos) # nyan
    grunt.config configPos, "spec"
    grunt.log.writeln('after modif with config: ' + grunt.config configPos) # spec 
    grunt.task.run('mochaTest')
```

Comment: Any reason you are not using `grunt-mocha`?

Comment: @kmiyashiro what makes you think I'm not?

Comment: `mochaTest`, `mochaTestConfig` etc

Comment: @kmiyashiro https://github.com/pghalliday/grunt-mocha-test; grunt-mocha is for client side, according to the grunt-mocha page.